# js clone object with properties pointing to function

Tags: javascript, function, properties, clone

In Javascript how to clone an object where one or more object properties point to a function ?

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))
```

The above does not work because in the course of stringify it loses the reference to the function.

Comment: You could implement something similar to jQuery's [$.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

Comment: Just use any of the many `clone` implementations that do not use JSON serialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) library. The best solution to manipulate Array and Object.

`var myCloneObject = _.clone(mySourceObject);`